# Using bash variables inside awk

Tags: bash, awk

Trying to pass the external "CLIENT_ID" variable into this line of awk, but it doesn't work as expected. This is what I've tried:

```
CLIENT_ID=1
awk -v CLIENT_ID="${CLIENT_ID}" 'NF{print "xxx_${CLIENT_ID}_" $0 ".sh"}' A.csv > B.csv
```

in A.csv

```
201712
201711
201710
```

Desired output in B.csv:

```
xxx_1_201712.sh
xxx_1_201711.sh
xxx_1_201710.sh
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
xxx_${CLIENT_ID}_201712.sh
xxx_${CLIENT_ID}_201711.sh
xxx_${CLIENT_ID}_201710.sh
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`${CLIENT_ID}` is bash syntax. You should instead use the `awk` syntax you're already using for `$0`:

```
awk -v CLIENT_ID="${CLIENT_ID}" 'NF{print "xxx_" CLIENT_ID "_" $0 ".sh"}' A.csv > B.csv
```